# Execute function after event completion (Inside Knockout Custom Binding)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have made a custom knockout binding to a date picker. The date picker has an event called changeMonth. I am hooking into this event and I want to execute a function on event completion (after monthChange as finished and the month on the date picker has changed). Below is the code that I have currently.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeMonth", function (event) {
        someFunction();
    });
}};
```

Currently someFunction is called before event completion. How can I hook this up so it gets called after event completion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up browsing through the datepicker code and just added an event trigger after the month has changed and hooked into that.